# Flask setup code run once, but not during tests

Tags: python, flask

I have setup code in my Flask app that initializes some database entries in Mongo and schedules cron jobs. How do I have this run once when the server starts but not when I run tests?

My project is structured as:

```
/crypto
    __init__.py
    main.py
    /templates
    /statis
    /tests
        tests.py
```

where the app object and setup code is in `main.py` and looks like

```
app = Flask(__name__)

...

with app.app_context():

    # do database setup

    # do cron job setup
```

My `test.py` needs to run `from crypto import main` to access the app object but the act of importing it also runs the setup code, which I do not want. Is there something I'm missing structurally here that would solve this?

---

@Hi I'm Frogatto, I tried adding `if __name__ == "__main__":` around the setup code, however then that code doesn't run when I start the server locally with `flask run`.

Answer (score 1):

When Python interpreter reads a `.py` file (for example when you `import` it), it will execute all of its code forthwith. So, in order to execute a piece of code when that `.py` file is the main module of the program, you would need to put your setup code in the body of the following `if`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # setup here.
```

This `if` ensures that your setup code runs when that `.py` file is the main module to run.

Comment: thanks for the response! I tried that but `flask run` doesn't execute the code in that section.

Comment: @Mike There's lots tweaks you can employ to overcome the problem: (1) Run server in the code not using `flask run` CLI. [example](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/flask-example/blob/master/wsgi/myflaskapp.py). (2) Avoid importing `main.py` by separating _the common_ part and importing that common part from `main.py` and the second module you're trying to import `main.py` from. (3) Using CLI try to init/setup your server. [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbinit/).